# Expose Package code via Flow instead of global methods

Tags: apex, managed-package, visual-workflow, isv, global-methods

I am thinking about an alternative way to expose Manage Package code to the outside world. Not using the problematic global class scope. And I thought why not package a Flow that calls the code and let the outside world initialize my Flow using

```
new Flow.Interview().start();
```

[image]

**Does that work? Any drawbacks? Or better alternatives?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we encapsulate the *outsider* class in an *outsider* flow, it does work, with a few points to take into consideration.

- By using the `createInterview` method from the [Interview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/flow_interview_class.htm) class, we can call a flow that has been defined outside of the package. This method give us the flexibility to run a flow dynamically. Then this outsider flow can contain an outsider class that executes your logic.
- If the outsider flow is in a different package, we need to provide the namespace to the `createInterview` method.

---

An example on how to call the flow dynamically:

```
Map <String, Object> inputs = new  Map <String, Object>();

Flow.Interview myFlow = Flow.Interview.createInterview(<namespace>?, <outsiderFlowName>, inputs);
myFlow.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

I've taken to using a single `DefaultCallable` global class per package that implements the shapeless platform [Callable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_Callable.htm) interface (i.e. `Map<String, Object>` arguments and `Object` return) and dispatches to my internal functionality. No type safety but completely flexible over time.

Callers (that don't want to be coupled i.e. that want to work with or without the package) can use code like this:

```
Type t = Type.forName('ns.DefaultCallable');
if (t != null) {
    Callable c = (Callable) t.newInstance();
    Object result = c.call('op', new Map<String, Object{...});
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

and cast/parse the result.

Maps work well as Apex has the nice `=>` operator to make setting them up easy, but JSON strings in and out is another option.